# How to combine boost::range with BOOST_<level>_EQUAL_COLLECTION?

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible to combine [BOOST__EQUAL_COLLECTION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html#) with [boost::range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) such that I can simplify:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

std::vector<int> mysort(std::vector<int>);
...

auto lhs = mysort({ 11, 7, 5, 3, 2 });
const std::vector<int> rhs = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
```

to something like

```
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(mysort({ 11, 7, 5, 3, 2 }), { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 });
```

Apart from being less verbose, I see the additional benefit of a more useful warning, which currently reads:

```
error in "foo": check { lhs.begin(), lhs.end() } == { rhs.begin(), rhs.end() } failed.
```

which really is not that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `boost::range` won't help you here. The problem is with how `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS` is defined.

You can define a macro yourself:

```
#define COLLECTIONS_CHECK_EQUAL(a, b) BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::end(b))
```

and use it as:

```
COLLECTIONS_CHECK_EQUAL(mysort(std::vector<int>{ 11, 7, 5, 3, 2 }), std::vector<int>{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 });
```